# Clojure function greater than 10 SLOC

Tags: clojure

It has been mentioned in the [Clojure Style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide) to avoid functions longer than 10 SLOC but mine has more than 10 (47 to be exact).

The code is an [web api implementation](https://github.com/psibi/clj-uclassify/blob/master/src/clj_uclassify/uclassify.clj#L166) and follows like this:

```
(defn classify
  "Sends a text to a classifier and returns a classification"
  [keys texts classifier & user-name]
  {:pre [(check-keys? keys)]}
  (let [textbase64-tag (map #(make-xml-node :textBase64
                                            {:id (str "Text" (str (index-of % texts)))}
                                            (String. (encode (.getBytes %)) )) texts)
        texts-tag (make-xml-node :texts {} textbase64-tag)
        user-attribute (if (> (count user-name) 0)
                         { :username (first user-name) })
        classify-tag (if (= (count user-name) 0)
                       (map #(make-xml-node :classify
                                            {:id (str "Classify" %)
                                             :classifierName classifier
                                             :textId (str "Text" %)
                                             })
                            (range (count texts)))
                       (map #(make-xml-node :classify
                                            {:id (str "Classify" %)
                                             :classifierName classifier
                                             :textId (str "Text" %)
                                             :username (first user-name)})
                            (range (count texts))))
        read-calls (make-xml-node :readCalls
                                  {:readApiKey (keys :read-key)}
                                  classify-tag)
        uclassify-response (raw-post-request
                            (xml/emit-str
                             (xml-append-elements uclassify
                                                  (list texts-tag read-calls))))]
    (if (check-response
         (get-response uclassify-response))
      (readable-list
       (list
        (x/xml-> uclassify-response
                 :readCalls :classify
                 :classification (x/attr :textCoverage))
        (map vector
             (x/xml-> uclassify-response
                      :readCalls :classify
                      :classification :class
                      (x/attr :className))
             (x/xml-> uclassify-response
                      :readCalls :classify
                      :classification :class
                      (x/attr :p)))))
      false ;; Will never reach here
      )))
```

The code initially builds all the associated xml tags within `let` and after building them sends a request to the server and then checks out the response to see if it succeeded.

Why I didn't handle the response in a separate function is because that it won't be reused again. Is this a good practice, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's value in factoring the logic out into one or more new functions, even if those functions are only used in a single place, because it can make the code easier to understand and modify.

In a situation like that (when the logic won't be used elsewhere) I often use `letfn`. The `letfn` could be either internal or external to the function itself but I see that as a purely stylistic decision.

[Here's](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/letfn) the ClojureDocs page on `letfn`. See [Pedestal's](http://pedestal.io/) [dataflow logic](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/master/app/src/io/pedestal/app/dataflow.clj) for a few examples of `letfn` in use.

On the other hand, there's really no problem with having a top level function that's only used in one place. I like that `letfn` implicitly communicates the function's scope of relevance, but I don't think either way is objectively superior to the other.

Comment: While it used to be accepted style to extract functions only for reuse, I find myself more often than not doing so to break up logic. Every function you extract removes the need for a comment explaining what's going on when you use a descriptive function name. And you're more likely to update a function name when changing the logic as compared to a comment.